# How can i get the arrays from the JSON file Dynamically

Tags: php, json

I have Json file which contain alot of Arrays. How can i get the the array Dynamically for each person by name like the get Parameter.

**JSON**

```
[{
    "Name": "Somename",
    "Lastname": "somelastname",
     "Address": "someaddress",
},
{
    "Name": "Somename1",
    "Lastname": "somelastname1",
      "Address": "someaddress1",
},
{
    "Name": "Somename2",
    "Lastname": "somelastname2",
     "Address": "someaddress2",
}}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$json_file = file_get_contents('jsonfile.json');

$someArray = json_decode($json_file, true); 

?>
```

**HTML**

```
 <a href="product.php?post=name">

 <h3 id="custompage"><?php echo $value["Name"]; ?>

<span><br><?php echo $value["Lastname"]; ?></span>

<span><?php echo $value["Address"]; ?></span>
</h3>

</a>
```

Comment: do you have a GET somewhere ? as in my answer, I used a hard-coded value, not knowing...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you need to do (find only one match, or fetch all), but this is for both :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array = array(
1 => array( "Name" => "Somename1", "Lastname" => "somelastname1", "Address" => "someaddress1"),
2 => array( "Name" => "Somename2", "Lastname" => "somelastname2", "Address" => "someaddress2"),
3 => array( "Name" => "Somename3", "Lastname" => "somelastname3", "Address" => "someaddress3"),
4 => array( "Name" => "Somename4", "Lastname" => "somelastname4", "Address" => "someaddress4")
);

$data1 = json_encode($array);
//var_dump($data1);

$data = json_decode($data1, true);
//var_dump(json_decode($data1));

$myname = "Somename3";

/* one liner to get one result */

if( array_search("$myname", array_column($data, 'Name')) == true ){ echo"[ $myname found ! ]"; } else { echo"[ no data match ! ]"; }

/* loop to get all results */

foreach($data as $user){
echo $user['Name'].' '.$user['Lastname'].' '.$user['Address'].'<br/>'; 
}

?>
```